# Remove mounted folder without unmounting device?

Tags: linux-mint

I wanted to mount my HDD which is used as a storage device to a directory.

I accidently selected my SSD which is used for booting the OS.

Now I have a folder named: `Storage` which is mounted to the SSD.

I wish to remove this folder because it is irrelevant, without unmounting the SSD, damaging something.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wish to remove this folder because it is irrelevant, without
>   unmounting the SSD, damaging something.
>
> Is this possible?

Yes, it’s possible and it’s safe.

When you unmount a device, you really just unmount the designated mount point. The underlying device that is connected to the mount point is not affected.

So go ahead and unmount `Storage`; right now it’s just acting as a secondary mount point for your SSD and unmounting it will just get rid of that secondary mount point.